# y-axis scale undefined within anonymous function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble seeing why the below code is not working for me.

**NOTE**: I am using D3 v4.

```
// DATA JOIN
var dataJoin = vis.svg.selectAll(".group")
  .data(vis.displayData);

// ENTER + UPDATE
var group = dataJoin.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "group");

group.append("path") // ENTER
  .attr("class", "line")
  .style("opacity", 0.5)
  .merge(group) // ENTER + UPDATE
    .transition()
    .duration(800)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return vis.y(d.beginDate); <------- vis.y() is undefined
    });
```

For each element in `displayData` I would like to create a **separate** custom path element (ie, custom shape) that is placed along the y-axis. Each path element needs to use the vis.y() scale in order for me to be able to place the path element on the appropriate point along the y axis.

HOWEVER, vis.y() is undefined inside of the .attr function call.  **Why?**  I've built other D3 visualizations (although, those were using version 3) and have used the scale inside of the .attr function call, so why is this having an issue now?

I'm basically trying to add a custom shape with a custom path for each element that starts at a different location on the y axis.  If you feel like I'm going about this the wrong way, feel free to give me other suggestions.

It uses the following scale:

```
vis.y = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([vis.height, 0]);

vis.y.domain([
  d3.min(vis.displayData, function(d) { return d.beginDate; }),
  d3.max(vis.displayData, function(d) { return d.endDate; })
]);
```

The data is an array of objects structured like the below:

```
var obj = {
  name: d.Name,
  type: d.type,
  beginDate: d.beginDate,
  endDate: d.endDate,
  eventDate: d.eventDate
};
```

Comment: I can't say why `vis.y` is undefined because you haven't shown enough code (ie how is vis created and in what scope)?  I'd recommend posting a complete code example that replicates the problem.  That said, am I missing something here, `vis.y` is a scale, it won't return a path's `d` string attribute.

Comment: @Mark, here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltjjj5p2/ but I wasn't able to replicate the problem.  If I add everything inside of a d3.json() function then `vis.y` is undefined.  Once I pull it outside of it it works.  So something makes me think it's a scoping issue maybe?

Comment: Actually, I think I found the culprit, but I'm still unsure why this would affect it.  My code is wrapped inside of `function loadData() { }`.  When the page loads I call `loadData();` directly.  When I remove the function call and pull the `d3.json()` data load outside of it `vis.y` is available.  Why is that?

Comment: Like Mark mentioned before, this will be impossible to tell unless you provide an example which reproduces this problem. As a side note: you need to use `.merge(dataJoin)` instead of `.merge(group)` to act on both, the enter **and** the update selection. `dataJoin` contains the update selection whereas `group` contains the enter selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was happening, but still can't explain WHY it's happening.  I'm going to provide two examples, both examples are exactly the same except for one line:

**Vis is undefined**

```
.attr("d", function(d) {
  return d.beginDate;
});
```

**Vis is defined**

```
.attr("d", function(d) {
  return vis.y(d.beginDate);
});
```

What I mean when I say "defined" vs "undefined" is, when I step through the code, break on the return statement, and then type "vis" in the console, in one case an object is returned and in another case the object is undefined.

When I declare vis.y() within the return statement before running the application for some reason the vis is defined, otherwise it's not.  These fiddles should show both the broken and working behavior (although, I couldn't put a break point in the actual fiddle because I have no idea where the JS lives in the "sources" view.  I ran both of them locally.).  Again, the only difference is the one line above.

**Broken** (vis is undefined)

https://jsfiddle.net/jtLp2wzg/

**Working** (vis is defined)

https://jsfiddle.net/39exh1s8/1/